# Configuring sbt to jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt

I'm trying to configure sbt plugin to jenkins but it doesnt show up sbt section in configuration section after installing [sbt plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin) in jenkins CI.

sbt configuration section is not available for me.

1. Installed sbt plugin under Manage Jenkins and restarted jenkins .
2. Then  Manage Jenkins `-->` Configure System

I'm running jenkins in windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sbt configuration is available at:

Manage Jenkins --> Global Tool Configuration